# Calculate the error sum of squares after deleting the ith observation when predicting the ith value

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a data set assignment_data_1.txt.
(For the data set contains The first column of data set is named eruption and the second column is named waiting time)

The question is:
Estimate the predicted values of eruption at every value of waiting time and calculate the error sum of squares. **Do the same exercise after deleting the ith observation when predicting the ith eruption time.**

For the first part, I have calculated the error sum of squares as

```
data = read.delim("assignment_data_1.txt", sep=" ")
x = data$waiting
y = data$eruptions


### Using formulas we derived::

# We then calculate the three sums of squares.
Sxy = sum((x - mean(x)) * (y - mean(y)))
Sxx = sum((x - mean(x)) ^ 2)
Syy = sum((y - mean(y)) ^ 2)

# Then finally calculate hat_0̂ and hat_1̂ . (Least Squares Approach)
beta_1_hat = Sxy / Sxx
beta_0_hat = mean(y) - beta_1_hat * mean(x)
c(beta_0_hat, beta_1_hat)

## Variance Estimation
y_hat = beta_0_hat + beta_1_hat * x
e = y - y_hat
n = length(e)
s2_e = sum(e^2) / (n - 2)   ## = data_summ$sigma
s_e = sqrt(s2_e)   #residual standard error
```

I don't know how to calculate the error sum of squares after deleting the ith observation when predicting the ith value.

Comment: I think they are asking for a loop where you have to omit each i observation and compute the error so you will have a large vector of errors!

Comment: I would write the code as a function of `X` and `Y` and then call the function with arguments `x[-i]` and `y[-i]` in a loop on `i`, like @Duck said. Note that upper/lower case `x` and `y` above are meant to make it clear the function's arguments are not the same as the values in the `.GlobalEnv`.

Comment: Yeah as Sir Barradas said, it is easy peacy to make the loop, in that way yu can check kind of bias or influence of outliers!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a textbook computation of the residual sum of squares of a linear regression `y ~ x`. It is mostly based on the OP's code, simplified and returning RSS, not RMSE.

```
RSS <- function(x, y){
  Sxy = sum((x - mean(x)) * (y - mean(y)))
  Sxx = sum((x - mean(x)) ^ 2)

  # Then finally calculate hat_0̂ and hat_1̂ . (Least Squares Approach)
  beta_1_hat = Sxy / Sxx
  beta_0_hat = mean(y) - beta_1_hat * mean(x)

  ## Variance Estimation
  y_hat = beta_0_hat + beta_1_hat * x
  e = y - y_hat
  s2_e = sum(e^2)
  s2_e
}

library(datasets)
data(faithful)

rss_all <- RSS(faithful$waiting, faithful$eruptions)
rss <- sapply(seq.int(nrow(faithful)), function(i){
  RSS(faithful$waiting[-i], faithful$eruptions[-i])
})
```

Now compare with the result of R's `lm`:

```
fit <- lm(eruptions ~ waiting, faithful)

identical(rss_all, sum(resid(fit)^2))
#[1] FALSE
all.equal(rss_all, sum(resid(fit)^2))
#[1] TRUE
rss_all - sum(resid(fit)^2)
#[1] -7.105427e-14
```

And plot the `rss` vector obtained by removing one data point at a time.

```
old_par <- par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(eruptions ~ waiting, faithful, main = "Old Faithful")
hist(rss, freq = FALSE)
abline(v = rss_all, col = "blue")
par(old_par)
```

[image]

Comment: @ChuckP Sorry for the previous comment, mistook you for the OP. The code is corrected now. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Here's two answers one in the spirit of what you're learning with almost no change to your code... then just for fun we'll skip all the intermediate steps your evil professor has you doing and go to the 21st century!

First take what you've done and " Do the same exercise after deleting the ith observation when predicting the ith eruption time." in the simplest fashion

```r
# Outside the loop create vectors for
# x, y, and our results
waiting <- faithful$waiting
eruptions <- faithful$eruption
results <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length(waiting))

for(i in 1:length(waiting)) {
   ### for each iteration pull out the ith row
   x <- waiting[-i]
   y <- eruptions[-i]

   ### Using formulas we derived::
   # We then calculate the three sums of squares.
   Sxy = sum((x - mean(x)) * (y - mean(y)))
   Sxx = sum((x - mean(x)) ^ 2)
   Syy = sum((y - mean(y)) ^ 2)

   # Then finally calculate hat_0̂ and hat_1̂ . (Least Squares Approach)
   beta_1_hat = Sxy / Sxx
   beta_0_hat = mean(y) - beta_1_hat * mean(x)
   c(beta_0_hat, beta_1_hat)

   ## Variance Estimation
   y_hat = beta_0_hat + beta_1_hat * x
   e = y - y_hat
   n = length(e)
   s2_e = sum(e^2) / (n - 2)   ## = data_summ$sigma
   s_e = sqrt(s2_e)   #residual standard error
   results[[i]] <- s_e
}

results
#>   [1] 0.4964930 0.4968008 0.4968657 0.4963710 0.4974332 0.4960875 0.4974101
#>   [8] 0.4939935 0.4974308 0.4972777 0.4968989 0.4962460 0.4973199 0.4974166
#>  [15] 0.4971033 0.4973906 0.4931566 0.4970464 0.4966397 0.4973511 0.4973083
#>  [22] 0.4974166 0.4961923 0.4971464 0.4949644 0.4950030 0.4970524 0.4972706
#>  [29] 0.4973200 0.4970198 0.4958322 0.4964282 0.4972012 0.4973579 0.4973891
#>  [36] 0.4974284 0.4973884 0.4958118 0.4952862 0.4973505 0.4973215 0.4959420
#>  [43] 0.4974056 0.4952429 0.4944807 0.4929779 0.4946062 0.4974305 0.4970839
#>  [50] 0.4961327 0.4936545 0.4972578 0.4968989 0.4958118 0.4965764 0.4965679
#>  [57] 0.4972510 0.4910579 0.4960010 0.4974190 0.4969607 0.4974333 0.4974348
#>  [64] 0.4965948 0.4947328 0.4956626 0.4973592 0.4957213 0.4938558 0.4932572
#>  [71] 0.4971088 0.4968494 0.4968355 0.4964797 0.4948284 0.4920628 0.4958604
#>  [78] 0.4963307 0.4974346 0.4950030 0.4970140 0.4974349 0.4956974 0.4968074
#>  [85] 0.4967723 0.4973481 0.4974131 0.4969985 0.4967947 0.4959374 0.4966261
#>  [92] 0.4960753 0.4974288 0.4950743 0.4932174 0.4954389 0.4973016 0.4974263
#>  [99] 0.4973841 0.4962011 0.4970210 0.4967872 0.4971624 0.4973996 0.4972818
#> [106] 0.4973030 0.4972507 0.4971479 0.4972526 0.4962174 0.4941448 0.4971228
#> [113] 0.4974279 0.4970589 0.4944601 0.4968887 0.4967997 0.4974271 0.4951940
#> [120] 0.4971208 0.4965546 0.4954722 0.4970956 0.4968494 0.4973110 0.4965507
#> [127] 0.4968631 0.4973230 0.4974337 0.4971334 0.4970011 0.4972252 0.4967089
#> [134] 0.4963978 0.4972373 0.4974234 0.4973972 0.4970889 0.4973963 0.4969273
#> [141] 0.4974336 0.4967372 0.4972761 0.4946013 0.4966428 0.4960562 0.4966505
#> [148] 0.4973050 0.4971236 0.4970130 0.4930077 0.4974253 0.4958866 0.4969792
#> [155] 0.4974158 0.4961714 0.4972035 0.4930272 0.4970130 0.4944364 0.4957216
#> [162] 0.4965662 0.4964460 0.4972966 0.4968855 0.4955436 0.4964046 0.4972544
#> [169] 0.4973753 0.4963195 0.4974074 0.4969635 0.4959256 0.4974194 0.4974079
#> [176] 0.4974102 0.4946972 0.4964514 0.4962764 0.4966931 0.4968238 0.4959256
#> [183] 0.4973468 0.4959106 0.4974255 0.4968095 0.4968453 0.4972373 0.4974342
#> [190] 0.4973953 0.4963045 0.4960605 0.4942049 0.4968949 0.4974339 0.4974336
#> [197] 0.4919247 0.4967829 0.4971654 0.4958850 0.4962391 0.4974331 0.4945308
#> [204] 0.4971653 0.4961920 0.4973145 0.4967798 0.4959451 0.4973961 0.4973996
#> [211] 0.4927708 0.4964033 0.4974303 0.4974304 0.4966714 0.4969503 0.4971683
#> [218] 0.4967171 0.4971276 0.4971484 0.4974288 0.4974212 0.4966365 0.4956719
#> [225] 0.4974326 0.4974340 0.4974223 0.4972150 0.4965075 0.4966759 0.4957833
#> [232] 0.4972731 0.4966816 0.4970721 0.4965546 0.4970317 0.4969462 0.4970169
#> [239] 0.4973498 0.4959277 0.4969701 0.4957315 0.4970889 0.4974346 0.4974319
#> [246] 0.4965148 0.4969635 0.4974291 0.4932012 0.4959555 0.4974346 0.4974267
#> [253] 0.4974111 0.4946972 0.4959294 0.4969500 0.4967684 0.4974267 0.4969434
#> [260] 0.4973100 0.4953635 0.4974239 0.4957811 0.4973468 0.4960384 0.4967913
#> [267] 0.4940237 0.4973666 0.4963052 0.4964300 0.4972640 0.4953511
```

21st century method using `lm` which does regression and a couple of packages to speed our work ;)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

lmresults <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(faithful)) {
   lmresults[[i]] <- faithful %>% slice(-i) %>% lm(eruptions ~ waiting, data = .)
}

results2 <- purrr::map(lmresults, ~ summary(.)$sigma) %>% unlist

results2
#>   [1] 0.4964930 0.4968008 0.4968657 0.4963710 0.4974332 0.4960875 0.4974101
#>   [8] 0.4939935 0.4974308 0.4972777 0.4968989 0.4962460 0.4973199 0.4974166
#>  [15] 0.4971033 0.4973906 0.4931566 0.4970464 0.4966397 0.4973511 0.4973083
#>  [22] 0.4974166 0.4961923 0.4971464 0.4949644 0.4950030 0.4970524 0.4972706
#>  [29] 0.4973200 0.4970198 0.4958322 0.4964282 0.4972012 0.4973579 0.4973891
#>  [36] 0.4974284 0.4973884 0.4958118 0.4952862 0.4973505 0.4973215 0.4959420
#>  [43] 0.4974056 0.4952429 0.4944807 0.4929779 0.4946062 0.4974305 0.4970839
#>  [50] 0.4961327 0.4936545 0.4972578 0.4968989 0.4958118 0.4965764 0.4965679
#>  [57] 0.4972510 0.4910579 0.4960010 0.4974190 0.4969607 0.4974333 0.4974348
#>  [64] 0.4965948 0.4947328 0.4956626 0.4973592 0.4957213 0.4938558 0.4932572
#>  [71] 0.4971088 0.4968494 0.4968355 0.4964797 0.4948284 0.4920628 0.4958604
#>  [78] 0.4963307 0.4974346 0.4950030 0.4970140 0.4974349 0.4956974 0.4968074
#>  [85] 0.4967723 0.4973481 0.4974131 0.4969985 0.4967947 0.4959374 0.4966261
#>  [92] 0.4960753 0.4974288 0.4950743 0.4932174 0.4954389 0.4973016 0.4974263
#>  [99] 0.4973841 0.4962011 0.4970210 0.4967872 0.4971624 0.4973996 0.4972818
#> [106] 0.4973030 0.4972507 0.4971479 0.4972526 0.4962174 0.4941448 0.4971228
#> [113] 0.4974279 0.4970589 0.4944601 0.4968887 0.4967997 0.4974271 0.4951940
#> [120] 0.4971208 0.4965546 0.4954722 0.4970956 0.4968494 0.4973110 0.4965507
#> [127] 0.4968631 0.4973230 0.4974337 0.4971334 0.4970011 0.4972252 0.4967089
#> [134] 0.4963978 0.4972373 0.4974234 0.4973972 0.4970889 0.4973963 0.4969273
#> [141] 0.4974336 0.4967372 0.4972761 0.4946013 0.4966428 0.4960562 0.4966505
#> [148] 0.4973050 0.4971236 0.4970130 0.4930077 0.4974253 0.4958866 0.4969792
#> [155] 0.4974158 0.4961714 0.4972035 0.4930272 0.4970130 0.4944364 0.4957216
#> [162] 0.4965662 0.4964460 0.4972966 0.4968855 0.4955436 0.4964046 0.4972544
#> [169] 0.4973753 0.4963195 0.4974074 0.4969635 0.4959256 0.4974194 0.4974079
#> [176] 0.4974102 0.4946972 0.4964514 0.4962764 0.4966931 0.4968238 0.4959256
#> [183] 0.4973468 0.4959106 0.4974255 0.4968095 0.4968453 0.4972373 0.4974342
#> [190] 0.4973953 0.4963045 0.4960605 0.4942049 0.4968949 0.4974339 0.4974336
#> [197] 0.4919247 0.4967829 0.4971654 0.4958850 0.4962391 0.4974331 0.4945308
#> [204] 0.4971653 0.4961920 0.4973145 0.4967798 0.4959451 0.4973961 0.4973996
#> [211] 0.4927708 0.4964033 0.4974303 0.4974304 0.4966714 0.4969503 0.4971683
#> [218] 0.4967171 0.4971276 0.4971484 0.4974288 0.4974212 0.4966365 0.4956719
#> [225] 0.4974326 0.4974340 0.4974223 0.4972150 0.4965075 0.4966759 0.4957833
#> [232] 0.4972731 0.4966816 0.4970721 0.4965546 0.4970317 0.4969462 0.4970169
#> [239] 0.4973498 0.4959277 0.4969701 0.4957315 0.4970889 0.4974346 0.4974319
#> [246] 0.4965148 0.4969635 0.4974291 0.4932012 0.4959555 0.4974346 0.4974267
#> [253] 0.4974111 0.4946972 0.4959294 0.4969500 0.4967684 0.4974267 0.4969434
#> [260] 0.4973100 0.4953635 0.4974239 0.4957811 0.4973468 0.4960384 0.4967913
#> [267] 0.4940237 0.4973666 0.4963052 0.4964300 0.4972640 0.4953511
```

**Do we get the same answer?**

```r
all.equal(results, results2)
#> [1] TRUE
```